# Gitkraken error - Error authenticating: agent list id failed"

Tags: git, ssh, gitkraken

I'm running Gitkraken.  I can view all the commits in the remotes, but when I try doing a Pull, I get the error "Error authenticating: agent list id failed".

I'm using the local SSH agent option in the Authentication settings.

I know that there's no problem with my key, because I've added it to pageant (which is running) and when I use Sourcetree to do a Pull, everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was reported before (for other operations) in [GitKraken issue 10](https://github.com/techwizrd/GitKraken/issues/10).

This error message comes from [`libssh2/src/agent.c#agent_list_identities()`](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/64ebfd8182a9b6e637e65c3059e3798e199274b3/src/agent.c#L620), and introduced in [commit 22a2de7, libssh2-1.2.7, June 2010](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/commit/22a2de73473fc4203d74fdc073c9dc52de19d974) (6+ years ago) by [Daniel Stenberg (`bagder`)](https://github.com/bagder). That refactored [commit 7b351ee](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/commit/7b351eed36197877160659b31fc8dcc8524f22f8) which introduced ssh-agent API in Dec. 2009 by [Daiki Ueno (`ueno`)](https://github.com/ueno).

[As mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280531/7490), this could be related to the OS, or to a process preempting the resources needed by libssh2 to list the identities managed by the ssh agent. Make sure no other GUI is running which might be using pagent at the same time GitKraken does.

Comment: I tried closing down SourceTree and I restarted pageant, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @MattEno Even after a reboot and no other applications running?

Comment: Yep, I've just tried it now.  Still the same problem.

Comment: @MattEno Is your private ssh key passphrase-protected?

Comment: I'm actually not sure, and don't know how to tell.  I was just given a .ppk file to use with pageant.  It's been working fine for Sourcetree.

Comment: I think the mentioned issue #10 wont go far because it wasn't opened on the correct repo (something named tha same but not related to Axosoft)

Comment: @webofmars Agreed. I wil check if it has been reported in the actual application issue list.